# #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns UNION error

Tags: php, mysql

I spend over two days fixing this query ,but i cannot find where my problem is.My ques is that the last UNION is causing some errors ,without it everything works perfect.
However in the last UNION i don't have different number of columns as MYSQL error state.
Here is the query :

```html
INSERT INTO email_queues (queueid, queuetype, ownerid, processed, recipient)
SELECT DISTINCT 323,
                'export',
                1,
                0,
                subscriberid
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT subscribers.subscriberid AS subscriberid
   FROM email_list_subscribers AS subscribers
   JOIN email_lists AS lists ON lists.listid = subscribers.listid
   AND lists.listid IN (34)
   WHERE subscribers.listid IN (34)
     AND ((subscribers.emailaddress LIKE '%a%'))
   UNION SELECT DISTINCT subscribers.subscriberid AS subscriberid
   FROM email_list_subscribers AS subscribers
   JOIN email_lists AS lists ON lists.listid = subscribers.listid
   AND lists.listid IN (37)
   WHERE subscribers.listid IN (37)
     AND ((subscribers.emailaddress LIKE '%kim%'))) AS T1
WHERE subscriberid NOT IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT subscribers.subscriberid AS subscriberid
     FROM email_list_subscribers AS subscribers
     JOIN email_lists AS lists ON lists.listid = subscribers.listid
     AND lists.listid IN (37,
                          34)
     WHERE subscribers.listid IN (37,
                                  34)
       AND ((subscribers.emailaddress LIKE '%a%'
             OR subscribers.emailaddress LIKE '%kim%')))
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT subscribers.subscriberid AS subscriberid
FROM email_list_subscribers AS subscribers
JOIN email_lists AS lists ON lists.listid = subscribers.listid
AND lists.listid IN (33)
WHERE subscribers.listid IN (33)
  AND ((subscribers.emailaddress LIKE '%v%'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different number of columns indeed. The last `UNION` number of column is only one column seleccted, where the first select you had selected 5 as following:

```
INSERT INTO email_queues (queueid, queuetype, ownerid, processed, recipient)
    SELECT DISTINCT 323,                -- These are five columns
                    'export',
                    1,
                    0,
                    subscriberid
    FROM
    (
       ....
    ) AS T1
    WHERE subscriberid NOT IN (... )
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT subscribers.subscriberid AS subscriberid -- This where is the error, only one column selected
    FROM email_list_subscribers AS subscribers
    JOIN email_lists AS lists ON lists.listid = subscribers.listid
    AND lists.listid IN (33)
    WHERE subscribers.listid IN (33)
      AND ((subscribers.emailaddress LIKE '%v%'))
```

You have to modify it like this in order to make it works:

```
INSERT INTO email_queues (queueid, queuetype, ownerid, processed, recipient)
SELECT DISTINCT 323,                -- These are five columns
                'export',
                1,
                0,
                subscriberid
FROM
(
   SELECT DISTINCT subscribers.subscriberid AS subscriberid
   FROM email_list_subscribers AS subscribers
   JOIN email_lists AS lists ON lists.listid = subscribers.listid AND lists.listid IN (34)
   WHERE subscribers.listid IN (34)
     AND ((subscribers.emailaddress LIKE '%a%'))
   UNION SELECT DISTINCT subscribers.subscriberid AS subscriberid
   FROM email_list_subscribers AS subscribers
   JOIN email_lists AS lists ON lists.listid = subscribers.listid AND lists.listid IN (37)
   WHERE subscribers.listid IN (37)
     AND ((subscribers.emailaddress LIKE '%kim%'))
) AS T1
WHERE subscriberid NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT subscribers.subscriberid AS subscriberid
                           FROM email_list_subscribers AS subscribers
                           JOIN email_lists AS lists 
                             ON lists.listid = subscribers.listid  
                            AND lists.listid IN (37, 34)
                           WHERE subscribers.listid IN (37, 34)
                             AND ((subscribers.emailaddress LIKE '%a%'
                                  OR subscribers.emailaddress LIKE '%kim%'))
                          )
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT -- You have to add these in order to make the query works
  323,              
  'export',
  1,
  0,
  subscribers.subscriberid AS subscriberid -- this is only one column you selected
FROM email_list_subscribers AS subscribers
JOIN email_lists AS lists ON lists.listid = subscribers.listid
AND lists.listid IN (33)
WHERE subscribers.listid IN (33)
  AND ((subscribers.emailaddress LIKE '%v%'))
```

---

**UPDATE**: You can also move that query inside the subquery, something like this

```
INSERT INTO email_queues (queueid, queuetype, ownerid, processed, recipient)
SELECT DISTINCT 323,                -- These are five columns
                'export',
                1,
                0,
                subscriberid
FROM
(
   SELECT DISTINCT subscribers.subscriberid AS subscriberid
   FROM email_list_subscribers AS subscribers
   JOIN email_lists AS lists ON lists.listid = subscribers.listid AND lists.listid IN (34)
   WHERE subscribers.listid IN (34)
     AND ((subscribers.emailaddress LIKE '%a%'))
   UNION SELECT DISTINCT subscribers.subscriberid AS subscriberid
   FROM email_list_subscribers AS subscribers
   JOIN email_lists AS lists ON lists.listid = subscribers.listid AND lists.listid IN (37)
   WHERE subscribers.listid IN (37)
     AND ((subscribers.emailaddress LIKE '%kim%'))

  UNION

  SELECT DISTINCT subscribers.subscriberid AS subscriberid -- this is only one column you selected
FROM email_list_subscribers AS subscribers
JOIN email_lists AS lists ON lists.listid = subscribers.listid
AND lists.listid IN (33)
WHERE subscribers.listid IN (33)
  AND ((subscribers.emailaddress LIKE '%v%')) 
) AS T1
WHERE subscriberid NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT subscribers.subscriberid AS subscriberid
                           FROM email_list_subscribers AS subscribers
                           JOIN email_lists AS lists 
                             ON lists.listid = subscribers.listid  
                            AND lists.listid IN (37, 34)
                           WHERE subscribers.listid IN (37, 34)
                             AND ((subscribers.emailaddress LIKE '%a%'
                                  OR subscribers.emailaddress LIKE '%kim%'))
                          )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved a lot of time .

Comment: Just one :) ,is there a way so that the last union part works same as UNION SELECT DISTINCT subscribers.subscriberid AS subscriberid
   FROM email_list_subscribers AS subscribers
   JOIN email_lists AS lists ON lists.listid = subscribers.listid AND lists.listid IN (37)
   WHERE subscribers.listid IN (37)
     AND ((subscribers.emailaddress LIKE '%kim%'))
) AS T1

Comment: No, unless you made the number of columns for the first select only one column.

Comment: @user3241849 - You can move it to the sub query.